# Lambdas and dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

Good day,

I'm confused with the following:

```
v = {}

v[-1] = lambda x: 1
v[0]  = lambda x: x

for k in range(1, n):    # k = 1...n-1   
    v[k] = lambda x: 2*x*v[k-1](x) - v[k-2](x)
```

generates an error `maximum recursion depth exceeded` when I call, say, `v[3](1)`, while this:

```
v = {}  

v[-1] = lambda x: 1
v[0]  = lambda x: x

v[1] = lambda x: 2*x*v[1-1](x) - v[1-2](x)
v[2] = lambda x: 2*x*v[2-1](x) - v[2-2](x)
v[3] = lambda x: 2*x*v[3-1](x) - v[3-2](x)
```

works just fine. I can't figure out what Python's complaints are in the first case. Suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Inbar Rose pointed out, k is a global, and is not evaluated when the lambda is created. However, there is a way to have python evaluate k at the declaration time :

```
for k in range(1, n):    # k = 1...n-1   
    v[k] = lambda x, k=k: 2*x*v[k-1](x) - v[k-2](x)
```

This `k=k` declares a variable `k`, local to the lambda, optional, with a default value that is the value of `k` at the moment of declaration.

Answer (score 3):

Lambdas in Python are closures. The arguments you give the Lmabda aren't going to be evaluated until the Lambda is evaluated. At that time, `k=n` regardless, because your iteration is finished.

Proof:

```
>>> l = {}
>>> for k in range(1, 10):
    l[k] = lambda x: k
>>> for v in l.values():
    print v('')


9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
```

Comment: also, using `dis` module, `dis.dis(v[1])` gives this interesting line : `10 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (k)` which shows that the value of k is not evaluated during the loop.

Comment: That's the problem alright...but you've haven't suggested a solution.

Comment: The question was "What is causing this behavior" And this answers that question. I can't provide a solution exactly because now that the OP is aware his plan is not going to work, he should come up with a new idea, and if he has problems with that he can come ask another question, besides, @njzk2 provided a solution which can work for the OP (though it may not be exactly what the OP wants)